# How to proper align table of contents in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents, alignment

I'm struggling with following problem: I have generated table of contents and one of the item has quite long title as seen on the screenshot below.

[image: long title]

And because of that long title the page number goes on the new line. And I'm fine with this, but for some reason it doesn't align with all other numbers. On the ruler it looks like this:

[image: ruler]

And when I try to move tab to the right position the number gets back on the previous line and this looks a lot more uglier, imo:

[image]

So how to I align that number to other number while keeping it on the new line?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This problem also occurs in Word 2010, so the solution may be the same. Try setting right indent for the paragraph that makes problem (e.g. to 0,5 cm, see the screenshot). The last word of the line should move to the next line and the page number will be properly aligned.

[image: Change right indent screenshot]